# ipython tab completion only to show imported functions from a module, not other imported modules

Tags: tabs, ipython, python-import

I like the `tab completion` in `ipython` to see which functions are available in an imported module. I am aware that imports in a module could be hidden from view in the tab completion if those imports were done with an underscore like `import os as _os`. Is there a way to avoid seeing imported modules if the imports were done without an underscore like `import os` only?

Example:

`with_underscore.py`:

```
import os as _os

def list(path):
    _os.listdir(path)
```

`without_underscore.py`:

```
import os

def list(path):
    os.listdir(path)
```

After importing the two modules into ipython

```
[1]: import with_underscore
[2]: import without_underscore
```

tab completion `without_underscore.<tab>` would yield `list os`, tab completion `with_underscore.<tab>` would yield `list` only, which is what I want. How could I get only `list` with tab completion without the underscore importing approach?